With flit exclude all files except 1
With flit, how do I exclude all files of a certain type, except one?
I am attempting to exclude all .md files except for README.md, based on how it works with .gitignore:
[tool.flit.sdist]
include = ["my_project/**/*.py", "README.md", "LICENSE"]
exclude = ["test/**/*", "docs/**/*", "*.md", "!README.md"]

Unfortunately, the README.md is still excluded, and the build fails. I think this is due to the default behavior:

Exclusions have priority over inclusions.

So what's the intended way to exclude all .md files, except for one?
